# how to convert string ($23.25) to Decimal -$23.25 in selenium with C#

Tags: c#

I am using xpath to get a string shown in a format like ($23.25) which should be converted to -$23.25. I have tried:

```
decimal.Parse(string, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.Number);
```

But this is not returning the negative value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `NumberStyles.Number` use `NumberStyles.AllowParentheses`.

```
var balance = decimal.Parse("($23.25)", NumberStyles.Currency | NumberStyles.AllowParentheses); // -23.25
```

If you would like to format it to "-$23.25", here is how :

```
balance.ToString("$0.00") // -$23.25
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept it as the answer so Xiaoy312 gets credit for his work and the question gets marked as answered. Thanks!